# possible to compare 2 separate models vs 1 model

Tags: nonlinear-regression, likelihood-ratio

Is it possible to compare likelihoods for two separate models, compared to a single model? An LRT like...

$\chi^2 \sim \frac{\text{loglik}_{\text{model1}} + \text{loglik}_{\text{model2}}}{\text{loglik}_{\text{combined model}}}$

I'm trying to compare spatial distributions of events for two groups in relation to a covariate.  group1 being an isolated subset of group 2.  The error from group 2, being so much bigger than group 1, is washing away signal from group 1 when I do the model the way I had originally planned (with counts of events).

So is there a test to see if the distribution for group 1, in relation to this covariate, is significantly different than group 2?  is the LRT described above appropriate (assuming we can describe the error distribution to form an appropriate likelihood function)?